# Custom Greenplum aggregate function with window

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, greenplum

I'm using Greenplum DB and I'd like to calculate median in a window, something like:

```
SELECT avg(var1) OVER (PARTITION BY var2 ORDER BY datetime 
                       ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FROM tbl...
```

Unfortunately median is not implemented in Postgres so I created my own aggregate using this example:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median

The problem is that this works when I use entire column but does not in a window (with OVER clause) returning error that 'prefunc' should be defined. Greenplum documentation confirms that:
http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/ref_guide/sql_commands/CREATE_AGGREGATE.html

The documentation and role of prefunc is not very clear for me. Do you have any example of defining custom Postgres aggregate function that supports windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a custom aggregate in GPDB you need to define a PREFUNC, which is not a parameter in regular Postgres.

In normal Postgres, an aggregate needs a starting state (e.g. `STYPE=numeric[]`) and a function that tells it what to do to add a new item to the current state (e.g. `SFUNC=array_append`). But in a distributed system like GPDB, which shuffles data around between nodes, how should a node receiving state from two places (ie, two arrays) combine both states? That is the role of PREFUNC. Then, finally the FINALFUNC can be called on the single combined state and returned.

In the example of computing median, all you need to do is add `PREFUNC=array_cat,` to the aggregate definition that you took from the [median example code](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Median). `array_cat` takes two arrays and returns them as a single combined array. I've tried it and it works for me, both as an aggregate as well as a window.

*(Note that the version that takes `numeric[]` works, but for some reason not the `anyarray` one. Seems to be for reasons not important to creating a window/aggregate function.)*

For more info on aggregates see the [GPDB docs](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4370/ref_guide/sql_commands/CREATE_AGGREGATE.html) that Lukasz referred to.

Comment: Great, glad it was helpful @Lukasz. If you feel the answer worthy, I'd much appreciate an upvote and [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this will work for Greenplum.  But, in modern versions of Postgres, you can use `array_agg()` as a window function.  So, for your particularly problem, the running median is:

```
select (array_agg(var1) over (partition by var2 order by datetime
                              rows between 10 preceding and current row
                             )[6] as running_median
```

EDIT:

Another method would use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.var1
        from t t2
        where t2.var2 = t.var2 and t2.datetime < t.datetime
        order by t2.datetime desc
        offset 5 limit 1
       ) running_median        
from t;
```

Comment: Greenplum is based on [PostgreSQL 8.2.15](http://greenplum.org/gpdb-sandbox-tutorials/) . I think array_agg() was not available in this version.

Comment: array_agg() is in GPDB.

Comment: array_agg() works but with group by not with window, I'm still receiving `ERROR:  aggregate functions with no prelimfn or invprelimfn are not yet supported as window functions`

Comment: @Lukasz . . . It does work with more recent versions of Postgres (yes, I tested this answer before posting it).